# Wrong format csv output in python

Tags: python-3.x

i have the following code that is working 99% - its taken me various attempts to get it right:

```
w = csv.writer(filename, lineterminator="\n")
    sC = []
    for i in sOut:
        #print("save", i[1:])
        sC.append(i[1:], "\n") #slice away first part

    sP = self.ids(sC)
    w.writerow(sP)      
    filename.close()
    print("You save ", filename) #To show on CLI

def ids(self, numbering):
    tally = 1
    for i in range(len(numbering)):
        id = str(tally)
        numbering[i].insert(0, id)
        tally = tally+1
    return(numbering)
```

The out put it should return inside a CSV file should look like this i.e. in separate columns:

```
 1  -4.885276794    55.72986221
 2  -4.885276794    55.72958374
 3  -4.883611202    55.72958374
```

Instead it returns it all in one row and with square brackets, commas and aprostophes all of which I do not want:

```
 ['1', -4.88527679443359, 55.7298622131348] ['2', -4.7475008964538, 55.9473609924319]   ['3', -4.79416608810425, 56.02791595459]
```

I know I am making some basic mistake somewhere however I just don't know what? All help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks Jemma

Comment: You want `w.writerows(saveProcess)` instead of `w.writerow(saveProcess)`

Comment: thank you you are right it works now!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As per juanpa should be w.writerows(saveProcess) instead of w.writerow(saveProcess)

all works!